# Which is the best way to say this?

Tags: word-usage

Are the following sentences correct and do they mean the same thing?

I am trying to say that he is trying to have his dreams realized.

a.  He is setting out to **square his dreams with** reality.

b.  He is trying to **make his dreams a reality**.

c.  He is trying to **turn his dreams into reality**.

d.  He is trying to **make his dreams fit reality**.

e.  He is trying to **fit his dreams with reality**.

f.  He is trying to **fit his dreams to reality**.

Comment: You asked this question before. (It seems it's now been deleted.) Aside from (possibly) e., all of these are grammatical. It's purely a matter of personal preference which to use. And . . . why would you not just write *He is trying to have his dreams realized* as you do in your summary?

Comment: In the future, edit your closed question, rather than delete it and post a new one.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to say this is "turn his dreams into reality", and "make his dream a reality". The others such as "square" or "fit" suggest that he is changing his dream.

> He always wanted to be a rock star, but at age 25 he had to fit his dreams to the reality that there are not many rock stars that play the flute. So he took a teaching course and now works at the local school.
>
> It takes a lot of luck to turn your dreams into reality.

Answer (score 1):

One common, idiomatic way to say this is:

> He is trying to make his **dreams come true**.

If that seemed too cliché, though, I like your option (b):

> **He is trying to make his dreams a reality.**

In this particular sentence, I’d avoid verbs like *fit* and *square*, and avoid prepositions like *to, with,* or *into*. But that’s mostly a style choice, and not a grammatical requirement.

[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+his+dreams+a+reality%2Cturn+his+dreams+into+reality%2Cfit+his+dreams+with+reality%2C+make+his+dreams+come+true&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) can be a valuable tool when trying to evaluate how natural a phrasing may sound, or how commonly it is used.